# Why does it say attempt to index 'pac' global (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null, global-variables, global

My friend sent me this script, and the error I get is

[ERROR] gamemodes/santosrp/gamemode/sh_pacmodels.lua:137: attempt to index global 'pac' (a nil value)
  1. PlayerSwitchWeapon - gamemodes/santosrp/gamemode/sh_pacmodels.lua:137
   2. UpdatePlayers - gamemodes/santosrp/gamemode/sh_pacmodels.lua:169
    3. unknown - gamemodes/santosrp/gamemode/cl_init.lua:105

sh_pacmodels 137 is this

```
function GM.PacModels:PlayerSwitchWeapon( pPlayer, entOldWep, entNewWep )
    if not pPlayer.AttachPACPart then
        pac.SetupENT( pPlayer ) --line 137
        pPlayer:SetPACDrawDistance( GetConVarNumber("srp_pac_drawrange") )
    end

    local invalid
    for slotName, _ in pairs( GAMEMODE.Inv.m_tblEquipmentSlots ) do
        item = GAMEMODE.Inv:GetItem( GAMEMODE.Player:GetSharedGameVar(pPlayer, "eq_slot_".. slotName, "") )
        if not item or not item.PacOutfit then continue end
        if not IsValid( entOldWep ) or not IsValid( entNewWep ) then continue end
        if item.EquipGiveClass == entOldWep:GetClass() or item.EquipGiveClass == entNewWep:GetClass() then
            invalid = true
            break
        end
    end
```

sh_pacmodels 169 is this

```
function GM.PacModels:UpdatePlayers()
    if not self.m_intLastThink then self.m_intLastThink = CurTime() +0.1 end
    if self.m_intLastThink > CurTime() then return end
    self.m_intLastThink = CurTime() +0.1

    local ragdoll, item
    for k, v in pairs( player.GetAll() ) do
        --Track active weapon
        if not v.m_entLastActiveWeapon then
            v.m_entLastActiveWeapon = v:GetActiveWeapon()
        else
            if v:GetActiveWeapon() ~= v.m_entLastActiveWeapon then
                self:PlayerSwitchWeapon( v, v.m_entLastActiveWeapon, v:GetActiveWeapon() ) -- line 169
                v.m_entLastActiveWeapon = v:GetActiveWeapon()
            end
        end
```

Comment: To get help on this question, suggest that you add a little bit more detail on what you're actually trying to achieve (what's the outcome you're looking for) and how you're trying to run this program.  As it is it's too broad and not really in a format people can easily help you with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pac` is not defined.

Yes it's that simple.

Comment: how do you define pac?

Comment: It's your friend's code. He should know what I mean.